# Let $R$ be a ring. For $a$ and $b$ in $R$, define $[a,b]=ab-ba$. Show that $R$ is commutative if and only if $[x^2,y]=[y,x]$ for all $x,y$ in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring. For $a$ and $b$ in $R$, define $[a,b]=ab-ba$. Show that $R$ is commutative if and only if $[x^2,y]=[y,x]$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $R$.

I have $[x^2,y]=x^2y-yx^2$ by the definition, and $[y,x]=yx-xy$. So that $x^2y-yx^2 =  yx-xy$, but then I don't how to proceed and show commutative.

Comment: Is R assumed to be an integral domain?

Comment: it just said its a ring

Comment: See http://archive.maths.nuim.ie/staff/sbuckley/Papers/bm_variations.pdf

Answer (score 3):

We have for $x,y\in R$
$$[x,y]+[x,y]=[x,y]-[x,-y]=[y^2,x]-[(-y)^2,x] =0,$$
hence also $$[x,y]=[y,x].$$
Then for $x,y,z\in R$ we have
$$ \begin{align}[x,z]+[y,z]
&=[x+y,z]\\
&=[(x+y)^2,z]\\
&=[x^2+xy+yx+y^2,z]\\
&=[x^2,z]+[xy+yx,z]+[y^2,z]\\
&=[x,z]+[xy+yx,z]+[y,z],
\end{align}$$
hence 
$$[xy+yx,z]=0. $$
Now 
$$\begin{align}[x,y]&=[x^2,y]\\
&=xxy-xyx+xyx-yxx\\
&=[x,xy]+[x,yx]\\
&=[x,xy+yx]\\
&=0, \end{align}$$
i.e., 
$$ xy=yx.$$